# Trying to Animate a keychain tag but not sure if it's a constraint or a rigid body?

Tags: constraints

I'm trying to animate the Blue Lever going 45degree's counter clockwise on the X-axis, and I need the tag ring to I guess parent or child to it, with the tag.  Not sure if I should use Rigid Body Constraints, or an Object Constraint to it. I'd be willing to pay for this info. lol. Thanks[image]